# How to write the mongoose functions given mongodb query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, filtering

This is the query to select the room document that contains user1 and user2.

```
db.getCollection("rooms").find({
$and:[            
    {users: ObjectId("5e2916615f55cc6e3cb9838b")},    
    {users: ObjectId("5e2b51107d1c624260620e9e")}    
   ]
})
```

It works well in mongodb shell and returns following documents.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e55ae0e07f8bf48dc602d1c"), 
    "users" : [
        ObjectId("5e2916615f55cc6e3cb9838b"), 
        ObjectId("5e2b51107d1c624260620e9e")
    ], 
    "label" : "", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e55ae98bec6265a48d453e6"), 
    "users" : [
        ObjectId("5e2916615f55cc6e3cb9838b"), 
        ObjectId("5e2b51107d1c624260620e9e")
    ], 
    "label" : "", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

I want to use this query in nodejs with mongoose.

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
import mongodb from "mongodb";

const RoomSchema = new Schema({
  users: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
      autopopulate: { select: "name phone photo" }
    }
  ],
  label: { type: String, text: true }
});

export default model("Room", RoomSchema);
... ... ...
const filter = {
        $and: [
          { users: new mongodb.ObjectID(uid1) },
          { users: new mongodb.ObjectID(uid2) }
        ]
      };
const items = Room.find(filter);
```

But it doesn't work. What's the mistake?

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (F:\work\find-stuff\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (F:\work\find-stuff\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at F:\work\find-stuff\backend\src\controllers\room.controller.ts:75:27
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at F:\work\find-stuff\backend\src\controllers\room.controller.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (F:\work\find-stuff\backend\src\controllers\room.controller.ts:4:12)
    at createItem (F:\work\find-stuff\backend\src\controllers\room.controller.ts:59:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
```

I was very confusing about this.

Comment: Does it return an empty array or something else? Do you await/then the promise returned in the last line of code?

Comment: i think you make the search query wrong !.

Comment: Thanks, @mickl, I was very silly. Missing "await" was the problem. Please write the answer article. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Model.find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) is an asynchronous operation which needs to be awaited / continued by using `.then()` or passing callback:

```
const items = await Room.find(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it should work

```
const filter = [
  { users: new mongodb.ObjectID(uid1) },
  { users: new mongodb.ObjectID(uid2) }
]

const items = Room.find({ $and: filter });
```

Comment: Sorry, but It occurs same exception.

Comment: In your find query you pass the object like `filter ={.......}` this  not work becuase when pass the multiple condition in find query that should pass in array like `filter=[]`

Comment: I found the reason. Missing 'await' was the problem. Thanks for your care.